# SQL Server Power function discrepanacy?

Tags: sql-server, function, math

The MSDN documentation at [POWER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx), 
 indicates that the first parameter past to it, is, or should be, convertible to a float

```
 POWER ( float_expression , y )
```

but when you Run

```
 `Select power(19.8, 2) withoutCast, 
         power(Cast(19.8 as float), 2) withCast`
```

you get:

```
withoutCast     withCast
------------    ----------------------
392.0           392.04
```

The correct value of course, should be 392.04.
The function returns the wrong answer when the input parameter is not pre-cast to a float.

This apparently is documented by the statement in the MSDN docs that:

"Returns the same type as submitted in float_expression. For example, if a decimal(2,0) is submitted as float_expression, the result returned is decimal(2,0)."

However, if I submit 19.8 as the first expression, why is the function assuming it is a decimal(19,0) and truncating the fractional portion of the answer????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the function return a wrong answer when the input parameter
>   is not pre-cast to a float?

No, the function is returning a value with the same number of decimals as the parameter unless you convert to a float.  Try this and note the decimals in the return:

```
select power(2.3, 2), power(2.33, 2), power(2.333, 2)
```

You may be missing the concept of [Significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) in terms of what is being passed back.  If you pass something in with an accuracy to 1 decimal value to a function, shouldn't it return back to that accuracy?

---

To take your example a bit further, try this:

```
Select power(19.8, 6) withoutCast, power(Cast(19.8 as float), 6) withCast
```

Here are the results:

```
withoutCast     WithCast
60254729.6      60254729.561664
```

Now, do you really think that value would be accurate to 6 decimal places given that I just raised it to the 6th power?  This is part of the context you are missing is how far can I go and still have accuracy with my results as some may think it is accurate to the 5th or 6th decimal which may not be true if you are extrapolating your data.

Comment: Yes I noticed this, if I send it 19.80, then it works. I see the logic, but this is very disturbing.  And no, I would expect the number of significant digits to be based on what the function does.   raising a decimal number to a power REQUIRES more decimal places in the result than in the input value.   If you ask for the average of 100 integers, all clustered within a few digits of the value 5, would you be happy to always get 5 for the answer ??  This seems like an oversight in the design requirements to me.

Comment: Depends on what format I expect the average to be expressed. If I take an integer answer then I would expect 5 as that is the answer.  Similarly, one can think of 3 divided by 2 and getting the answers of 1 if it is integer division and 1.5 if it is rational division.  There is something to be said for the context of the operation.

Comment: What I expect based on my requirements is a different question from what the function does by default. By default, it should not lose precision.  If I  execute `Select 2.2 * 2.2` it does not assume that in "context", because I am multiplying decimal(9,1) values it should generate a decimal (9,1) result of 4,0, does it???  No, it generates the correct result of 4.04. - So why should it do that when executing any other math function ?   nevertheless, +1 for explaining how this works...

Answer (score 0):

It's returning the same precision as it was passed...

```
Select power(19.8, 2),power(19.80, 2),power(Cast(19.8 as float), 2)
```

returns this:

```
392.0    392.04    392.04
```

casting to float is safest way to go.